# How can I install Agda on iSH?

Tags: ios, unix, jailbreak

I want to use Agda in iSH.

Agda seems to suggest you need cabal to install it. I don’t know why (as in, if you could build it from source, without Cabal). Perhaps Agda is written in Haskell.

https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.3/getting-started/installation.html

If I try a straightforward approach, I can see cabal here:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/cabal

But apk add cabal returns:

```
iPhone:~# apk add cabal
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  cabal (no such package):
    required by: world[cabal]
iPhone:~#
```

It appears for some reason iSH does not have the complete apk packages:

https://ish.app/blog/default-repository-update

But I added them from here:

```
echo https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main >> /etc/apk/repositories
echo https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community >> /etc/apk/repositories
sed -i -e '/http:\/\/apk.ish.app/d' /etc/apk/repositories
```

https://github.com/ish-app/ish/wiki/Using-Alpine-Linux-repositories

and did apk update.

But it still doesn’t find them.

Why?

Comment: It’s not clear what the issue is here.  Agda requires cabal - it is what it is.  As far as iSH goes, it’s 64bit per the [FAQ](https://github.com/ish-app/ish/wiki/FAQ#q-is-ish-32-bit-or-64-bit).  Please [edit] with some clarifications and keep in mind, it must be focused on *one* topic - Agda or iSH

Comment: It’s intrinsically about both. The issue is that iSH has a special version of apk (which I don’t understand) so you cannot rely on normal apk packages being available. When I do apk add cabal it says package not found. I’ll update the post with that info. Thanks.

Comment: Does running `apk -vv add cabal` offer any clues? Also, `apk -U` might help by updating the cache.

Comment: -vv returned identical output, -U had no difference. I put the question to some AI agents and got some advice. One is that there may be a known bug regarding adding Alpine repos: https://github.com/ish-app/ish/issues/1518 . Possibly, you can download a particular “mini x86 file system”? I suppose I should learn more about how to check and confirm that it’s actually accessing whatever repos I have put in my apk/repositories directory.